# anyway to let mvc framework validate my action parameter, just like ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have an action and want to do some simple check on param

```
ActionResult Test([Range(0,10)] int i)
{
  // ModelState.IsValid is always true, i want it to be false if i > 10 or i < 0
}
```

anyway to fix this or work around it or any alternatives provided by MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of just checking the data annotation attribute definition before giving you some alternate options. I surprised to see that the `AttributeUsage` is defined in such that you can apply to the method parameters as well and unfortunately it not worked as i tried myself. Though I'm not sure why they have allowed this parameter to method parameters (I see it's valid but not working)

Regarding alternate options you could try this,

```
public ActionResult Test(int i)
{
   var rangeAttr = new RangeAttribute(0, 10);

   if(!rangeAttr.IsValid(i))
     ModelState.AddModelError(i.ToString(), rangeAttr.FormatErrorMessage("i"));       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well in mvc the most appropriate way to do it in you model simply put a attribute

```
 [Range(0,10)]
 public int yourproperty{ get; set; }
```

read this 
     http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own error if its outside that range and that would make IsValid false.

So for example you could do something like

```
    if(i < 0 || i > 10)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Range", "Invalid Range");
```

I believe that should work.